# After installing pyglet, module has no Attributes or anything

Tags: python, pyglet

I just installed pyglet with pip3 to try some new things out. I go to try out some of the sample code from the pyglet website to create a window that displays some text.

```
import pyglet
window = pyglet.window.Window()
```

The rest of the code is meaningless to continue on with because if I run the code I get:

```
AttributeError: module 'pyglet' has no attribute 'window'
```

So I figure okay, let me look and see what's inside the module.

```
help(pyglet)
```

And all I get is:

```
Help on package pyglet:

NAME
    pyglet

PACKAGE CONTENTS


FILE
    (built-in)

(END)
```

What I don't understand is why the module has nothing in it? Also, I did install pyglet with pip install before and for some reason it doesn't import with python2. If I run it with python2 I get:

```
ImportError: No module named pyglet
```

But pip list shows that I do have it as does pip3.

Comment: [pyglet](https://pyglet.readthedocs.io/en/pyglet-1.3-maintenance/) supports both python2.x and python3.x, i've just tried here on windows with python3.6 and it works out of the box, try uninstalling first and installing back without using the cache and please report the installation process, otherwise we don't have any clues to help you out to figure out what's going on. For instance, `--no-cache-dir`

Comment: You have named your own script `pyglet.py` and so `import pyglet` is importing that.

Comment: No, I haven't named anything as such.

Comment: I did just fix python2 though. For some reason pip installing doesn't really do anything. But if I apt-get install python-pyglet it works.

Comment: Unfortunately, there isn't a python3-pyglet package to install. Maybe it's because I'm running Linux on top of Chrome OS? Not sure but I've had some bugged out things happen where things work one day and then the next it's a different story.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I uninstalled pyglet using pip for both Python2 and 3. Before I installed pyglet again using pip, pyglet was still installed. For some reason pip doesn't do anything on my system. If I want to install a python module I do it from the package manager apt. So I don't know what's going on here exactly but I got it working with Python2, but there isn't a pyglet package for Python3.

Comment: For the time being, this is my fix.

Answer (score 0):

I copied and pasted your code, and that seems to work fine in 2.7 after I used pip to install pyglet. So It most likely is an issue with your installation. Try uninstalling both of the pyglet modules from pip and pip3 and retrying.

If that doesn't work, try doing a `pip install --upgrade pip` to update your pip and try again.